# Is there a way to customize the text of C# VS intellisense autocomplete?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

When I'm in a rush and want to code some straightforward functionality, the C#, Visual Studio intellisense autocomplete is a very useful tool. However, there are some auto-generated code, that do not fit my code-style. For example, when create a property, the default code is:

```
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

The code that would fit my style, when I add the public accessibility to the field later, is something like:

```
    public int MyProperty
    { 
        get
        {

        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
```

I understand, that there is a *propfull* keyword, that generates a private field for the property and a best practice is the actual generated code for the *prop* keyword (if you define public property). But I was wondering if there is way to define a complete to define an auto-complete keyword for intellisense. I fear that the answer is no. But, is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I could not find this MSDN topic before with the help of google, but reading the Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework lead to the appropriate place.

Anyway, if anybody would like to create a custom code snippet, check out [Investigating Code Snippet Technology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379562#codesnippets_topic3) MSDN topic.